# When can we invert a multivariable relation?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that I give you an implicit relation $f(x,y,z)=0$. Now I ask when can you assure me the existence of a function that maps $(x,y)\to z$ as given by the above relation? Locally? Globally?

Comment: This is exactly what the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) is about.

Comment: I think that the implicit function theorem doesn’t say about inverting a single multivariable relation w.r.t. *one* of its input variables.

Comment: Oops! I never encountered the many-variable form of the theorem before! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), a relation $f(x,y,z) = 0$ can be written in the form $z = g(x,y)$ about some point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ satisfying the relation if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}|_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)} \neq 0$.

Comment: Can you say anything about global behaviour?

Comment: Definitely not from the derivative.  I don't know of any reasonable conditions that guarantee global behavior.