# Why can a surface at any point locally be given as a graph?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Can someone please explain why if given a parametric surface there is a function $z=f(x, y)$ or $y=g(x, z)$ or $x=h(y, z)$ so that the surface is given as a graph of that function? I know i have to use the implicit function theorem. I just don't know how exactly.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3462650/81360) answer your question?

Comment: No it doesn't because i still don't know how the implicit function theorem connects with a surface in parametric form.

Comment: Hint: What does it mean for a surface to be in parametric form?

Comment: It means that the surface is given as  r(u, v) =(x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v)). I know that somehow i must use the fact that the vector r_u outerproduct r_v is non zero since the surface is regular. But i still have trouble figuring out how exactly.